# mLab throws Authentication error code 18

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, mlab

I am trying to use mLab on my node.js server. My mongoDB shell version is v3.6.2, mongod version of the database is 3.4.11 (MMAPv1) 
 and using mac os high sierra.
I am using my database user's username and password

```
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'Authentication failed.',
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'Authentication failed.',
code: 18,
codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
```

Comment: Can you post the your server side code for establishing the mLab connection?

Comment: Hi, if you're still having issues, you can always email support@mlab.com.  We might be able to provide more in-depth support with authentication issues over email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While authenticating, use `'username'` and `'password'` not `<username>` and `<password>`. Get rid of `'<'` and `'>'`